# Remember Class Names on Refresh of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried a few different ways to do this and can't get it right.

The script on scroll adds a class of '.prod__viewed' whenever a div enters the viewport, so what I would like to is have the browser remember which divs have '.prod__viewed' on reload of the page, I have tried session storage but it's not quite there.

```js
$(window).on('resize load scroll', function() {
  $('.prod__item').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prodInViewport()) {
      $(this).addClass('prod__viewed');
    }
  });

  var numItems = $('.prod__item').length;
  var totalNumItems = $('.prod__viewed').length;
  var prodCountCheck = $('.prod__count__container');
  var positionY = $(this).scrollTop();
  var pageHeight = $(this).height();
  var scrollHeight = $('.prod__wrapper').height();
  var scrollPercent = (positionY / (scrollHeight - pageHeight)) * 100;
  var prodCountElement = $('.prod__count__container').outerHeight();

  if (prodCountCheck.length == 1) {
    $('.prod__count__content')
      .html('<span>You&#39;ve seen <strong>' + totalNumItems + '</strong> of <strong>' + numItems + '</strong> prods</span>');

    $('.prod__load__bar').css({
      'top': prodCountElement,
      'width': scrollPercent + "%"
    });
  }
});

$.fn.prodInViewport = function() {
 var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

sessionStorage.setItem("prodViewed", 
$(".prod__item").addClass("prod__viewed"));


if (sessionStorage.getItem("prodViewed")) {
    $(".prod__item").addClass(sessionStorage.getItem("prodViewed"));
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none
}

.header__content {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.prod__wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.prod__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.prod__item {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.prod__item--img {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.prod__item--img img {
  left: 50%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: auto;
}

.prod__name {
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.prod__price {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.prod__count__wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.prod__count__container {
  align-items: center;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.prod__count__content {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

.prod__load__bar {
  background: dodgerblue;
  height: 6px;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.random__content {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="prod__wrapper">
  <div class="prod__container">
    <div class="prod__item">
      <div class="prod__item--img">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="prod__item--deets">
        <div class="prod__name">
          My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
        </div>
        <div class="prod__price">
          £14.99
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prod__item">
      <div class="prod__item--img">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="prod__item--deets">
        <div class="prod__name">
          My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
        </div>
        <div class="prod__price">
          £14.99
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prod__item">
      <div class="prod__item--img">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="prod__item--deets">
        <div class="prod__name">
          My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
        </div>
        <div class="prod__price">
          £14.99
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have a working CodePen here: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/vYYoVZR

Comment: Can you also add the code you were using for session storage?

Comment: Session storage; like localStorage and cookies; are key/value pairs, you cannot store objects or html elements this way, you need to save their id or a different string reference, since `.addClass()` will return the jquery element and you cannot store that directly. Unrelated: keep in mind that we have vw, vh, vmin and vmax now as relative units, so half the jquery code for resizing can be replaced by CSS.

Comment: Side note; your logic for setting the localStorage is outside of the scroll event handler.  So you're never live updating your sessionStorage as your DOM changes.

Comment: your ```sessionStorage.setItem``` runs as soon as your page loads and adds the ```prod__viewed``` class to all of your items, so the scroll function is not doing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it working as you wanted.
In the scroll function, I add the index of the element in view to an array and save that array to the session Storage. 
Then when the page loads I get the array of indexes of the objects already viewed and add the classes to that elements.

Here is a working fiddle since stack overflow doesn't let you to access to the session storage due to security reasons.
https://jsfiddle.net/9dftzw8m/1/

```js
$.fn.prodInViewport = function() {
 var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

Array.prototype.pushUnique = function (item){
    if(this.indexOf(item) == -1) {
        this.push(item);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


$(window).on('resize load scroll', function() {
 $('.prod__item').each(function() {
  if ($(this).prodInViewport()) {
   $(this).addClass('prod__viewed');
      
      let prodsViewed = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem("prodViewed") ) || [];
      prodsViewed.pushUnique( $(this).index() );
      sessionStorage.setItem("prodViewed", JSON.stringify( prodsViewed ) );
  }
 });
 
 var numItems = $('.prod__item').length;
 var totalNumItems = $('.prod__item.prod__viewed').length;
 var prodCountCheck = $('.prod__count__container');
 var positionY = $(this).scrollTop();
   var pageHeight = $(this).height();
 var scrollHeight = $('.prod__wrapper').height();
 var scrollPercent = (positionY / (scrollHeight - pageHeight)) * 100;
 var prodCountElement = $('.prod__count__container').outerHeight();

 if (prodCountCheck.length == 1) {
  $('.prod__count__content')
   .html('<span>You&#39;ve seen <strong>'+totalNumItems+'</strong> of <strong>'+numItems+'</strong> prods</span>');
  
  $('.prod__load__bar').css({
   'top': prodCountElement,
   'width': scrollPercent+"%"
  });
 } 
});


const viewedItemsIndexList = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem("prodViewed") );
if( viewedItemsIndexList ) {
  for ( let i = 0; i < viewedItemsIndexList.length; i++) {
    $( ".prod__item" ).eq(viewedItemsIndexList[i]).addClass("prod__viewed");
  }
}
```

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 font-size: 62.5%;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
    
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

body {
 background: #fff;
   color: #333;
   font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.6rem;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin: 0;
}

a {
 color: #333;
 text-decoration: none
}


.header__content {
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 1.8;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
}


.prod__wrapper {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 60px;
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
}

.prod__container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin-left: -20px;
 margin-top: -60px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

.prod__item {
 flex-basis: 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 60px;
}

.prod__item--img {
 height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.prod__item--img img {
 left: 50%;
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   width: auto;
}

.prod__name {
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 1.2;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.prod__price { margin-top: 10px; }

.prod__count__wrapper {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 40px;
 max-width: 500px;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

.prod__count__container {
 align-items: center;
 background: darkblue;
 color: white;
 display: flex;
 font-size: 20px;
 height: 60px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

.prod__count__content {
 position: relative;
 top: -1px;
}

.prod__load__bar {
 background: dodgerblue;
 height: 6px;
 left: 0;
 max-width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}


.random__content {
 padding-left: 20px; 
 padding-right: 20px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 60px;
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
}

/* .prod__viewed {background: red;} */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="header__content">
 <h1>Counting Them Divs, Yo!</h1>
 
 <p>This script will count up any div that has been seen inside of the viewport and give a handy little count so you don't lose track, also added a sweet loader bar just in case :D</p>
 
 <p><strong>Give it a scroll!</strong></p>
</section>


<section class="prod__count__wrapper">
 <div class="prod__count__container">
  <div class="prod__count__content"></div><!-- /.prod__count__content -->
 </div><!-- /.prod__count__container -->

 <div class="prod__load__bar"></div><!-- /.prod__load__bar -->
</section><!-- /.prod__count__wrapper -->


<section class="prod__wrapper">
 <div class="prod__container">
  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->

  <div class="prod__item">
   <div class="prod__item--img">
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Lz-p7eRDL._SL1500_.jpg">
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--img -->

   <div class="prod__item--deets">
    <div class="prod__name">
     My Hero Academia Two Heroes Blu Ray
    </div><!-- /.prod__name -->

    <div class="prod__price">
     £14.99
    </div><!-- /.prod__price -->
   </div><!-- /.prod__item--deets -->
  </div><!-- /.prod__item -->
 </div><!-- /.prod__container -->
</section><!-- /.prod__wrapper -->



<section class="random__content">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>

 <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.</p>

 <p>Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus.</p>

 <p>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante.</p>

 <p>Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus.</p>

 <p>Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris.</p>

 <p>Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus.</p>

 <p>Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac</p>
</section><!-- /.random__content -->
```

Comment: Thank you! Cheers for the explanation too as I've never delved this deep into session storage before so it's slightly confusing and most resources online assumed a click was involved haha.Thanks!

Comment: This does seem to throw back some errors in the console :/

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @NickElse You are right, it throws an error on the ```viewedItemsIndexList.lenght``` function, because the first time you enter the page the ```viewedItemsIndexList``` object is not created on the session storage, just add and if condition around it. My mistake, I will update the answer. Check if this solves the issue.

Comment: @NickElse Also, clean the your sessionStorage using ```sessionStorage.clear()``` command, your ```Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1``` error can be happening because your ```sessionStorage``` is still containing things from your previous code. I'm not being able to reproduce that error.